# gradle fails at compiling sample project (appcompat-v7:23.3.0)

Tags: android-studio, appcompatactivity

I'm trying to clone Udacity Android's Basics course project. I've cloned the project from GitHub and imported it in my Android Studio 2.1.2.

When I try to run it, gradle generates errors as follow:

```
Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0
Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0
```

I've updated all my SDKs but it still generates the error.

Also when I click on "Install Repository and Sync Project" link in the gradel messages, it says:

```
Following packages are not available:
Package id: extras;android;m2repository
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong, why exactly gradle is not working, and how can I fix it?

Comment: if you're using windows, navigate to where you downloaded Android SDK (where SDKManager.exe) is located, and see if this file path exists `extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the simple steps:

1) Open any android project which is working on your SDK.

2) Open the build.gradle(Module:app) file.

3) copy the dependencies

eg:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
}
```

4) paste them in your current project.

5) Also see the

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
```

They should match with what ever is written after v7 support library (android_support_lib_version).

6) Finally sync the project once again.

Comment: Thanks, I set the version to 23.2.1 and it worked. But out of curiosity, what package should I update so the project works with 23.3.0?

Comment: It basically depends on what SDK version you are using to compile your project and that should match the android support library versions. You can go to SDK Manager and then check the SDK build tools.